# Склеить, объединить фото (jpeg карта)

Tags: c#, изображения, jpeg

Есть много файлов одной карты `COLUMN_LINE.jpeg` все файлы одинакового размера - `256х256 px`.

Как их можно склеить в один файл `jpeg`?

P.S.:
Если входные файлы `001_001.jpeg` `001_002.jpeg` `002_001.jpeg` `002_001.jpeg`, то полученный `map.jpeg` будет `512х512 px`.

---

Простите, пожалуйста. Может я не достаточно явно описал проблему.

Уточняю: входных файлов может быть очень МНОГО (например 100х100=10 000 изображений). И надо запусть это на 4 ГБ RAM (ну учитывая, что и система должна как-то работать).

---

На 10 000 не тестил. Просто загрузить такое количество картинок напряжно. Но поделюсь кодом с помощью которого произвел склейку.

И еще я напутал - у меня `.png`,а не `.jpeg`. Но принцип тот же. Разница есть, но кому надо разберетесь.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;

class IMGhelper
{
    public int NeedCOLUMN; // я знаю сколько должно быть колонок
    public int NeedLINE; // я знаю сколько должно быть строк
    // потому что я сначала задал программе скачать это кол-во колонок и строк

    private string[,] m_filesExist; // тут будут хранится пути ко всем картинкам

    private void getFiles() // будьте осторожны! Этот метод работает в МОИХ условиях
    // У вас тут может выпасть ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ!
    {
        m_filesExist = new string[NeedCOLUMN, NeedLINE];
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Map\\", "*.png"); // маленькие картинки в папке Map
        foreach (string dir in dirs)
        {
            // мои файлы называются ххх_ххх.png (например 017_010.png)
            string[] tmp = Path.GetFileName(dir).Split('.')[0].Split('_');

            int col = int.Parse(tmp[0]); // тут 017
            int row = int.Parse(tmp[1]); // тут 010
            m_filesExist[col, row] = dir;
        }
    }

    public void ImgCombine()
    {
        readFiles();
        // Создаем новый image нужного размера (это будет объединенный image)
        Image img = new Bitmap(256 * NeedCOLUMN, 256 * NeedLINE);// у меня каждое изображение 256x256 px

        // Делаем этот image нашим контекстом, куда будем рисовать
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);

        // рисуем существующие маленькие image в созданный нами большой image
        for (int c = 0; c < NeedCOLUMN; c++)
        {
            for (int r = 0;r < NeedLINE; r++)
            {
                g.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(m_filesExist[c,r]), new Point(256*c, 256*r));
            }
        }

        // Записываем обобщенный image в файл рядом с исполняемым файлом

        img.Save("output.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

И вызов

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IMGhelper IH = new IMGhelper();
    //у меня 600 изображений из них должно получится 20 колонок и 30 строк
    IH.NeedCOLUMN = 20;
    IH.NeedLINE = 30;

    IH.ImgCombine();
}
```

Comment: `Image.FromFile(m_filesExist[c,r])` - это в переменную и в `using` надо.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а зачем загруженную картинку в переменную сохранять? Я всего один раз к ней обращаюсь.

Comment: Чтобы вызвать на ней Dispose и освободить ресурсы, с чем замечательно справляется using-блок. Иначе до запуска сборщика файл с картинкой будет заблокирован (для записи), а все связанные с ним ресурсы будут удерживаться приложением. `using (var img = Image.FromFile(m_filesExist[c,r])) g.DrawImage(img, new Point(256*c, 256*r));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так:

1. Создаёшь Bitmap нужного размера
2. Graphics.FromBitmap
3. По нужным координатам рисуешь куски через Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled
4. Сохраняешь Bitmap в файл

Comment: А такой вариант сможет запуститься на 4 ГБ RAM, если входных изображений буде 5 000?

Comment: @Илья, не знаю. Но это пишется достаточно легко, чтобы просто взять и проверить.

Comment: в моем случае все отработало. Но я клеил не более 2000 файлов. Спасибо за отклик.

Comment: Очевидно, размер _физической_ памяти не играет особой роли, имеет значение размер _виртуальной_ памяти.